# Extract specific information from many xml files

Tags: xml, search, powershell

I have a script which is exporting our users software and run registry keys to xml files in order for us to track suspicious files. I have several hundred xml files which consists of:

```
<MDetection>
   <SoftwareReg>
      <Soft1>HKCU\SOFTWARE\Adobe</Soft1>
      <Soft2>HKCU\SOFTWARE\Ask.com</Soft2>
      <Soft3>HKCU\SOFTWARE\Citrix</Soft3>
      <Soft4>HKCU\SOFTWARE\Google</Soft4>
      ...
   </SoftwareReg>
   <RunReg>
      <Run1>SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Run\Sidebar-->C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe /autoRun</Run1> 
      <Run2>SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Run\WindowsWelcomeCenter-->rundll32.exe oobefldr.dll,ShowWelcomeCenter</Run2> 
      ...
   </RunReg>
   <Hostname>USERPC01</Hostname>
   <Username>JonesA</Username>
   <TimeGenerated>03/01/14 11:00</TimeGenerated>
</MDetection>
```

I would like to be able to search all the XML files for a particular SoftwareReg or RunReg key and also be able to search for entries using a wildcard. For example search for all 'Ask.com' keys or entries beginning with 'cr'.

The problem I am having is that I would like to know the Hostname and the Username that the corresponding reg key refers to. I am unable to extract these.

My Xml Powershell is not the strongest so any assistance would be appreciated! I am currently using:

```
   $XmlData = Select-Xml -Path '\\Server\Share$\*.xml' -XPath '//MDetection' -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue'
   $XmlData | %{$a += $_.Node.SoftwareReg.ChildNodes.'#text'}
```

I am using $a to temporarily store all the reg entries but I cannot extract the hostname or username. I suspect there is an easier way of doing it that that I am currently using!

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `select`ing the information into custom objects:

```
$XmlData | select @{
    n='Software';e={$_.Node.SoftwareReg.ChildNodes.'#text' | ? {$_ -ne $null}}
  },
  @{n='Hostname';e={$_.Node.Hostname.ToString()}},
  @{n='Username';e={$_.Node.Username.ToString()}}
```

The above creates objects where the property `Software` holds an array with the registry paths. For transforming the hierarchical data into tabular data you could try something like this:

```
$XmlData | % {
  $username = $_.Node.Username.ToString()
  $hostname = $_.Node.Hostname.ToString()

  $_.Node.SoftwareReg.ChildNodes.'#text' | ? { $_ -ne $null } |
    select @{n='Software';e={$_}},
      @{n='Hostname';e={$hostname}},
      @{n='Username';e={$username}}
}
```

Comment: Great and thanks - I am now getting all 3 pieces of information however not in the right format. I need each <Soft> entry per line - at the moment I am getting the whole <SoftwareReg> node.

Comment: @kr0me You're getting an array with the text values from the `<SoftwareReg>` node. See updated answer for a way to create tabular output.

Answer (score 0):

I am having to to do a similar sort of thing.

The method for doing so utilises XSLT, which you can learn about here http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp
The tutorial should be enough for what you want. The language can be made to do quite complex things.

Comment: Thanks, however is it not possible using Select-Xml and Select-String?

Answer (score 0):

Realizing that using regex to parse XML may be considered heresy:

```
$search = 'Ask.com'
$Rsearch = [regex]::Escape($search)

$regex=@"
(?ms)<MDetection>
   <SoftwareReg>.+?$Rsearch.+?
   </RunReg>
   <Hostname>(.+?)</Hostname>
   <Username>(.+?)</Username>
   .+
"@


(Get-Content file.xml -Raw) -match $regex > $nul
$matches


Name                           Value                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                 
2                              JonesA                                                                
1                              USERPC01                                                              
0                              <MDetection>...
```